# Embedded jetty implementing HttpSessionListener

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I am trying to implementing HttpSessionListener interface with embedded jetty with proxy servlet, I have registered SessionListener, but it is not getting invoked at all, here is the code,

```
   public class JettyProxy {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server();
        CustomProxyServlet customProxyServlet = new CustomProxyServlet();


        ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
        connector.setPort(8888);
        server.addConnector(connector);

        ConnectHandler proxy = new ConnectHandler();

        server.setHandler(proxy);

        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(proxy, "/",
                ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        ServletHolder proxyServlet = new ServletHolder(customProxyServlet);

        context.addServlet(proxyServlet, "/*");

        if (context.getSessionHandler() == null) {
            System.out.println("Session handler is null");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Session handler is not null");
        }

        if (context.getSessionHandler().getSessionManager() == null) {
            System.out.println("Managaer it null");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Manager is not null");
        }

        context.getSessionHandler().addEventListener(new CustomSessionHandler());

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }

}
```

SessionHandler is not null, session creating events are not getting triggered, please help me, what is the procedure get session events?

Answer (score 2):

you should have a SessionManager. i usually use :
 org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager.HashSessionManager()
and
org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.SessionHandler(SessionManager manager)

then you should set the handler for the context

```
context.setHandler(sessionHandler);

sessionHandler.addEventListener("Your Session Listener");
```